# Where do I find Odrin?

Tags: the-witcher-2

In Chapter 2 of The Witcher 2, I've been tasked with finding a drunk man named Odrin by a few other drunk people. Normally this wouldn't be very high on my priority list, only, well...

**They won't shut up about him.**

Everywhere I go around camp and everything I do, be it fighting in a tournament, arm-wrestling the mercs for cash or discussing difficult politics with political people, I hear them shouting his name. It's really ruining the mood.

> Ooooooooooodriiiiiiiiiiiiin, where are yooooooou?

But seriously, where is he?

Comment: hahaha, I was thinking the exact same thing. Luckily its a rather quick quest to complete, after that they'll shut up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will find him at the Pontar riverbank (7).

[image]